# Using not() with a table row

Tags: jquery

I am doing the following:

```
$("#bl tbody").on("click", "tr", function () {
}
```

This executes the code inside the function whenever a row is clicked.

How do I prevent the code from executing if the click occurs *inside* a textbox *dynamically* added to the row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to exclude `input` text like:

```js
$("table tr").on("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target.type != "text")
    alert("ok");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
      test
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: got my answer! Accepting in 5 mins

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$("#bl tbody").on("click", "tr", function () {
  // your code in this block
}).on("click", "input[type='text']", function (e) { // chain this
   e.stopPropagation(); // stops the event to bubbleup
})
```